# How to obtain the excitation voltage of a synchronous motor rated in horse power?

Tags: synchronous-motor

The synchronous motor rated at 120 hp, 460 V and 0.78 p.f-leading. The synchronous reactance is 2.51 Ω and armature resistance is 0.023 Ω. Since no frequency given in the question, how do we obtain the excitation voltage of the motor?

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the excitation voltage of the synchronous motor, we need additional information such as the synchronous reactance and the field current. However, since you have already provided the synchronous reactance \$2.51\space\Omega\$, we can proceed with the calculations.

The excitation voltage of a synchronous motor can be determined using the following formula:

$$\text{excitation voltage}=\text{synchronous reactance}\cdot\text{field current}\tag1$$

To find the field current, we need to calculate the apparent power \$\text{S}\$ of the motor using the given information:

$$\text{S}=\frac{745.7\cdot\text{rated power [horsepower]}}{\text{power factor}}=\frac{745.7\cdot120}{0.78}=114723.08\tag2$$

The apparent power can also be calculated as:

$$\text{S}=\text{voltage}\cdot\text{current}=460\cdot\text{current}\tag3$$

From this, we can calculate the current:

$$\text{current}=\frac{\text{S}}{\text{voltage}}=\frac{114723.08}{460}=249.39\space\text{A}\tag4$$

Now we can determine the field current by considering the current flowing through the synchronous reactance:

$$\text{field current}=\frac{\text{current}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{synchronous reactance}}{\text{armature resistance}}\right)^2}}=\frac{249.39}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2.51}{0.023}\right)^2}}=2.28522\space\text{A}\tag5$$

Finally, we can calculate the excitation voltage:

$$\text{excitation voltage}=\text{synchronous reactance}\cdot\text{field current}=$$
$$2.51\cdot2.28522=5.73591\space\text{V}\tag6$$

Therefore, the excitation voltage of the synchronous motor is approximately \$5.73591\space\text{V}\$.

---

So, we can make a formula:

$$\text{V}_\text{e}=\frac{1}{\text{V}}\cdot\frac{745.7\cdot\text{P}_{\text{[hp]}}}{\varphi}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_\text{s}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\displaystyle\frac{\text{R}_\text{s}}{\text{R}_\text{a}}\right)^2}}\tag7$$

Where \$\text{V}_\text{e}\$ is the excitation voltage, \$\text{V}\$ is the supply voltage, \$\text{R}_\text{s}\$ is the synchronous reactance, \$\text{R}_\text{a}\$ is the armature resistance, \$\varphi\$ is the power factor and \$\text{P}_{\text{[hp]}}\$ is the rated power in horsepower.